# Muktzeh in the drawer: remove stuff?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, muktzeh

If I have a Muktzeh item in a drawer, can I still get my shirts out of that drawer on Shabbat?

Comment: @AdamMosheh your edits are pushing out new posts, and not allowing them to be seen. Do you think you could slow down and do them over time?

Comment: @Daniel - Yes, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this discussion by Rabbi Dovid Ostroff](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/ostroff/archives/shabbos30.htm). The drawer is a *basis* for that which is mutar and assur, so it depends which is more important, which is defined by Rav Moshe Feinstein based on his present needs and by Rav Shlomo Zalman Aurbach as a more absolute level of importance.